# Close function using bubbling

Tags: javascript

I  have implemented a custom dropdown which has a close function using bubbling, and I used to have only one dropdown on the page. But now I have two dropdowns and if I open the first dropdown and click on the second dropdown my first dropdown doesn't close. How I can fix it?

My close function using native JS:

```
add_event(document, 'click', function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    if (!event.keyCode) {
        var elem = event.target;

        while (elem !== document) {
            if (elem && elem.className === 'dropdown') {
                return;
            }
            elem = elem.parentNode;
        }

        close();
    }
}, false);
```

Link to my dropdown: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv7ou8mp/

Comment: Kindly, share a jsfiddle link if possible to support your answer. Please clear your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add an event listener to your document for each dropdown. Each dropdown shall close itself when this event is received.

```
document.addEventListener('closeDropdown', close);
```

Now create a function to fire this event:

```
function dispatchCloseEvent() {
    var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
    evt.initEvent('closeDropdown', true, false);
    document.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

Finally, before a dropdown opens, we're going to call this function to make sure other dropdowns in the document will get closed.

The `open` function now looks like this:

```
function open() {
    dispatchCloseEvent();
    dropdown_content.classList.remove('hidden');
    dropdown_content.scrollTop = 0;
    is_open = true;
}
```

And this is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lv7ou8mp/1/